# POST data from View to Controller via AJAX in Laravel 5

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax, laravel

## Data

I have a data

```
var data = [];
data['upnp_enabled'] = $("#upnp-switch").val();
```

When I `console.log(data);`  I got `[upnp_enabled: "true"]`

---

## Ajax

I've tried to make a **PUT** to my Controller via **AJAX**

```
var ajax = $.ajax({
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('value')},
    url: '/' + currentCPE + '/vlan/' + currentPageVLAN + '/upnp',
    type: 'PUT',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data
    //data: JSON.stringify(data) <---- I even tried this, same result !!
});
ajax.done(function (data) {
    parseMsgData(data, "Setting saved");
    console.log(data);
});
```

---

## Controller

Then In my Controller, I have this

```
public function update_upnp($cpe_mac, $vlan_id){

    $inputs = Input::all();
    dd($inputs);

}
```

---

I kept getting in my **Network Tab** > **XHR**

> []

---

I expect to see something like this for my `dd($inputs);`

`[upnp_enabled: "true"]`

---

Can someone please fill in what I missed ?

Comment: see var p=$("#upnp-switch").val(); console.log(p); what result u got?

Comment: How are you putting the route?

Comment: instead of dd ,use var_dump($inputs); see what result u get?

Comment: @Borna : Your `p` should return this `[upnp_enabled: "true"]`

Comment: @OrlandoCharles : Here is my route `Route::put('/{cpe_mac}/vlan/{id}/upnp', 'NetworkController@update_upnp');` , it is working because I know my dd is running. But it spit out the wrong data.

Comment: @Borna : `var_dump($inputs);` also return `[ ]`

Comment: Could you try passing the Request to the method like this `update_upnp(Request $request, $cpe_mac, $vlan_id)` and then using `$request->all()`, maybe there would be no difference, but, I think it worth trying

Comment: public function update_upnp(Request $request)
    {
     if($request->ajax()){
      $inputs=$request->all();
      var_dump($inputs);
     }
    }

Comment: @ihue can u add #upnp-switch view part??

Comment: Your data is not valid json. Also where is the console.log() returning what you think it is? In the `.done()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. First the request should be something like (notice that data is a JSON and not an array):

```
var data = {};
data['upnp_enabled'] = $("#upnp-switch").val();

var ajax = $.ajax({
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('value')},
    url: '/' + currentCPE + '/vlan/' + currentPageVLAN + '/upnp',
    type: 'PUT',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data
    //data: JSON.stringify(data) <---- I even tried this, same result !!
});
ajax.done(function (data) {
    parseMsgData(data, "Setting saved");
    console.log(data);
});
```

In your controller you may need to have something like:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function update_upnp($cpe_mac, $vlan_id, Request $request){

    return $request->input();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

in your controller you need the following

1. make sure that you are using the Request Class. :

   use App\Http\Requests;
2. you need to accept the Request through your method as an argument

   ```
       public function update_upnp($cpe_mac, $vlan_id, Request $request){
         dd($request->attribute);
       }
   ```

Good Luck